# Copy Large Text File into Arrays by Matching Regex

Tags: c#, regex

Occasionally I need to look through a roughly 25 MB Oracle Datapump SQLFILE (plain text) for a few key strings of text. I currently use some handy features in UltraEdit that make this not so bad. However, I have some other users who do not have UltraEdit and aren't familiar with Reg Expressions to find the right values.

If I wanted to create two Collections and add only lines matching a certain RegEx to each, where should I start? Should I use the plain StreamReader and StreamReader.ReadLine() to move through the file? Or would the size of the file suggest a different option?

The end result would be to output the contents of the Collections to the screen or a new text file, but I'm not too worried about that detail yet.

Please be as general or specific as you can be, I'm not immune to filling in what details I can for myself.

Comment: what are you trying to match!

Comment: The Regex string would be something like "^(TABLESPACE)/s/.{5,10}" for instance. I'm more concerned with the Open and Parsing of the file into the Collections in a somewhat quick and efficient manner. Thank you for asking.

Answer (score 2):

Starting with .NET Framework 4 you can use the `File.ReadLines` method that returns an `IEnumerable<string>` and thus does not hold the whole file in memory.

```
var lines = File.ReadLines(path).Where(s => myRegex.IsMatch(s));
```

Answer (score 0):

> Should I use the plain StreamReader and StreamReader.ReadLine() to move through the file? Or would the size of the file suggest a different option?

That's the approach I would take. Using a stream does not load the entire file into memory and so seems perfect for large files.

For each line, you can test if it matches and copy that line to the corresponding list. Or, if you are concerned about too much data, copy each line to one of two output files (also using streams).